# Сравнить два списка и вывести недостающие элементы (с сохранением количества)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь получить все элементы списка *list_a*, которых нет в списке *list_b* (с сохранением количества):

```
list_a = ['users1_', 'users1_', 'users2_', 'users3_']
list_b = ['users1_', 'users3_']
list_c = list()

for template in list_a:
    if template not in list_b:
        list_c.append(template)

print(list_c)  # ['users2_']
```

Но получаю только один элемент. **Что требуется сделать, чтобы получить ['users1_', 'users2_']** ?

Что-то вроде:

```
print(list(set(list_a) ^ set(list_b)))
```

не подходит, поскольку мне важны все элементы списка. Здесь *set* не подходит, так как он оставит только уникальные элементы в списках.

Comment: В списке b есть элемент users1_

Comment: Эникейщик - Да. Но нет второго элемента "users1_", который есть в списке list_a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если элемент найден, то удалить из списка b:

```
for template in list_a:
    if template not in list_b:
        list_c.append(template)
    else:
        list_b.remove(template)
```

Comment: Ваш вариант проще выглядит :)

Answer (score 3):

А так?

Разницу добавляем в `list_b`:

```
list_a = ['users1_', 'users1_', 'users2_', 'users3_']
list_b = ['users1_', 'users3_']
list_c = []

for x in list_a:
    num_a = list_a.count(x)
    num_b = list_b.count(x)
    if num_a > num_b:
        list_b.append(x)
        list_c.append(x)

print(list_c)  # ['users1_', 'users2_']
```

Comment: По условию не подходит. Нужно получить на выходе: ['users1_', 'users2_']. То есть, разницу списков.

Comment: @Владимир, обновил ответ

Answer (score 2):

Если порядок элементов в результирующем списке не важен, зато важна производительность.

```py
from collections import Counter

list_c = list((Counter(list_a) - Counter(list_b)).elements()) # ['users1_', 'users2_']
```

Comment: О, тоже думал через Counter решение написать, но думал сложнее будет. Круто ))